# How to run a ps1 script after deploying to AKS using devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, containers, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I would like to run a powershell or batch script after deploying my container into AKS (Azure Kubernetes Services) using Azure devops.

Deployment of my web api (containerized) to AKS is working. But, I want to run a script inside the container after deploying.

Is there a way to add a task in devops pipeline? Or is there another way to do this.

Follow up question, the reason I wanted to run a shell inside the container is to execute this command, `dotnet ef update database` to run my migration. But it needs to install the EF Core migration inside the container. Not sure if that is the best way since running the migration inside the app Startup will work. Is there a way to run the migration via shell without installing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a command inside a running pod you can use the kubectl client binary with the exec command

Within azure devops this thread will show you two ways

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9365

One uses the bash task with kubernetes command “login”

This will work if you didn’t enable the azure add integration.

Another approach is to use the azure CLI task

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/master/docs/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli.md

This way you can retreivd the cluster credentials using get-credentials. Then install the CLI (kubectl) and you should be all set to run kubectl exec.

Comment: My reason for running powershell inside the container is to run `dotnet ef update database`. I want to run my DB migrations using the script during deployment.

But when running the dotnet command, I was not able to run the script because, I think for .NET CORE 3 they excluded the migration on the dotnet cli. 

Is there a better way to run the update database?

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.andreavallotti.tech/en/2017/10/using-ef-cores-migration-with-docker-and-mysql/ it seems that you might need to install an extra package in your container for your command to work. 

Another approach that I read was to issue the migration in the code directly at startup.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually executing my migration at startup for now but planning on running it outside of the application. Will look into the link you provided. Thanks.